# Codeigniter php: SQL injection prevent

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, code-injection

I've finished one application, but while developing haven't checked about sql injections and now at the end, i need to fix this little issue.

Here's my code, how could i on easiest way fix this to prevent sql injection (is there any function just to format my username, password parameters, not to change my code).

```
public function getArtistByUsernameByPassword($username, $password) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM artists WHERE username = '$username' AND  password = ' $password'");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    return null;
}
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Codeigniter's [query builder class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html).

So your code would look like this.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('artists', array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
```

Comment: A more "sugary" syntax would be $this->db->from->('artists')->where('username',$username)->where('password',$password)->get();

Comment: You may also want to add a limit to the query if this query is for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Use `db->escape()` and `db->escapestr()` functions to avoid sql injection...